# Grails + AuditLogging replacementPatterns

Tags: grails, design-patterns, logging, audit

I met some problem when I tried to configure AuditLogging plugin for grails.
There is an example from documentation:

> replacementPatterns = ["local.example.xyz.":""] // replace with empty string.

I've made:

> replacementPatterns = ["UPDATE":"Aktualizacja"]

unfortunately event names are still "UPDATE" when "Aktualizacja" is expected.

Have anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue :I did it in the below way:
1. Should have an entry  in your config.groovy file :

auditLog.replacementPatterns = ["UPDATE":"replacement"]

2.In my Project plugin.groovy file ,inside the

```
def doWithSpring = {


       println application.config?.auditLog?.replacementPatterns  // prints [UPDATE:replacement]
          if (manager?.hasGrailsPlugin("hibernate")) {
            auditLogListener(AuditLogListener) {
                grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
                sessionFactory   = sessionFactory
                verbose          = application.config?.auditLog?.verbose?:false
                transactional    = application.config?.auditLog?.transactional?:false
                sessionAttribute = application.config?.auditLog?.sessionAttribute?:""
                actorKey         = application.config?.auditLog?.actorKey?:""
                logIds           = application.config?.auditLog?.logIds?:false
                replacementPatterns = application.config?.auditLog?.replacementPatterns?:null
                propertyMask        = application.config?.auditLog?.propertyMask?:""
            }
          }
        }
```

3.If you check the AuditLogListener in the AuditLog plugin code :
You will find the `replaceByReplacementPatterns(eventName,obj)` this replaces the eventName with the replacement pattern .

Regards